# How to compute ecrecover parameters in solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, erc20

There are many answer which explain how to compute `_r`, `_s`, `_v` with an other language.
But how to compute parameters in solidity itself ? Is there a built-in function like `ecrecover` ?

Comment: I´m [having really a hard time](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/15911/25002 "I cannot modify the smart contract") at [doing it with web3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/49299/25002). Converting hex values to a binary form usable by web3 is an example. I think I need to find a way at doing it with solidity since I'm unable to get the exact code and my intent is to operate with code already written in solidity.

Comment: And $3 lost! https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc0ed3b391d6f17ef62139611b7a4f774c08b991e354e1d3c668c3f8520c0bf56. I really need to switch to full solidity.